# How to get an image from Firebase into a RecyclerView using Picasso

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am having an issue getting images from my firebase realtime database. The images are in the storage and I have a link to them in the database but when I try to get the image to show in a recyclerview, the app crashes as it tries to load the records. I have the dependencies added in the gradle.app and I have grated the use of Internet

Code to fetch the data

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RestaurantViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Restaurant restaurant = restaurantList.get(position);

    holder.title.setText(restaurant.getTitle());
    holder.address.setText(restaurant.getAddress());
    holder.cuisine.setText(restaurant.getCuisine());
    holder.duration.setText(restaurant.getDuration());
    holder.PriceRange.setText(restaurant.getPriceRange());

    Picasso.with(context).load(restaurantList.get(position).getImage()).resize(120,90).into(holder.imageView);
}
```

Code to set the data

```
public class RestaurantViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView title, address, cuisine, duration, PriceRange;
    ImageView imageView;

    public RestaurantViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        address = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAddress);
        cuisine = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCuisine);
        duration = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDuration);
        PriceRange = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPriceRange);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewImage);

    }
}
```

Set/Get Methods

```
public class Restraunt{

public Restaurant(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}
    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Crash log

```
04-20 20:30:14.528 30759-30759/nci.wherenow E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: nci.wherenow, PID: 30759
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Context must not be null.
    at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso$Builder.<init>(Picasso.java:701)
    at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.with(Picasso.java:662)
    at nci.wherenow.RestaurantAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RestaurantAdapter.java:48)
    at nci.wherenow.RestaurantAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RestaurantAdapter.java:19)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6482)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6515)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5458)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5724)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3109)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22104)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:934)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:973)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22104)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6584)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22104)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6584)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:400)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22104)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6584)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22104)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6584)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22104)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6584)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:722)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22104)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2441)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1522)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1775)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1410)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6834)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:778)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:713)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:952)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Updated Crash Log:

```
04-20 20:37:12.153 855-855/nci.wherenow E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: nci.wherenow, PID: 855
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class nci.wherenow.Restaurant does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zze(Unknown Source:45)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzb(Unknown Source:198)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zza(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source:10)
    at nci.wherenow.Restaurant_Results$1.onChildAdded(Restaurant_Results.java:58)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzecw.zza(Unknown Source:71)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeia.zzbyc(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeig.run(Unknown Source:71)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
04-20 20:37:12.154 855-855/nci.wherenow E/UncaughtException: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class nci.wherenow.Restaurant does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zze(Unknown Source:45)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzb(Unknown Source:198)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zza(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source:10)
    at nci.wherenow.Restaurant_Results$1.onChildAdded(Restaurant_Results.java:58)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzecw.zza(Unknown Source:71)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeia.zzbyc(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeig.run(Unknown Source:71)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Crash update 2

```
04-20 20:45:41.030 4227-4227/nci.wherenow E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: nci.wherenow, PID: 4227
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Context must not be null.
    at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso$Builder.<init>(Picasso.java:701)
    at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.with(Picasso.java:662)
    at nci.wherenow.RestaurantAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RestaurantAdapter.java:48)
    at nci.wherenow.RestaurantAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RestaurantAdapter.java:19)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6482)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6515)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5458)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5724)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3109)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22104)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:934)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:973)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22104)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6584)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22104)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6584)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:400)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22104)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6584)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22104)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6584)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22104)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6584)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:722)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22104)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2441)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1522)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1775)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1410)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6834)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:778)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:713)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:952)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-20 20:45:41.031 4227-4227/nci.wherenow E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Can you post your crash logs !

Comment: Added the crash log

Comment: `Context must not be null` . You are passing null context to Picasso .

Answer (score 0):

//Declare your restaurant empty constructor in your model;

Restaurant.java

```
public Restaurant() {
    }
public String getImage() {
return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}
```

Main class:-
replace your code onBindViewHolder

```
Restaurant restaurant = new Restaurant();
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(restaurant.getImage()).resize(200, 200).into(holder. 
imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your activity , pass 'this' to adapter like :

```
RecyclerAdapter r = new  RecyclerAdapter(this);
```

Then in your RecyclerAdapter class constructor :

```
Context context; // global
public RecyclerAdapter(Context context){
this.context = context;
}
```

Comment: Is the crash log same ? Can you post your updated crash log?

Comment: Updated log has been added

Comment: check updated answer , if there still a crash then post your updated crash then

Comment: newest crash log added

Comment: @CarlO'Beirne : Did it help ?

Answer (score 0):

Your context is null , this is the problem , try to pass the context from the activity (the place where you added the adapter to the recycler view) to the RestaurantAdapter (to the constructor) and use it with picasso.

use getBaseContext()  in your activity( where you created an instance of the Restaurent adapter) and pass it to the adapter contructor and use it in picasso.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to initialize context. you can pass it to adapter constructor as mentioned above. Or you can defined static context in your Application class  and initialize it in the Application class onCreate method. But the first one is more likely way.

Comment: In the logs it said that the context that you are passing as Picasso init param is null.